# Using GDP to predict Probability of Default

Tags: r, predictive-models, econometrics

I would appreciate if you could help me to answer on how to use the GDP (Gross Domestic Product) to predict the probability of default (Probability of corporate defaulting in their payment). By using the GDP, I would like to stimulate a probability  of default in different scenarios. For an example, when the GDP is increasing by how much will the probability  of default decrease and so on. I am also using the R software to get my results but I am not able to find the stats or library to use.

[image]

This an example of the data. **Now the main thing I am trying to achieve is. When GDP is expected to drop by a certain percentage, how many notches higher would my probability of default would be?**

Comment: Not sure if the guy was close to you, my condolences. Nonetheless, not all members here are familiar with the terms you used, please define what is GDP and Z factor. Also, try to better define your problem, what type of model you look for, any package you might have tried.  If you can't disclose the data that you're using, showing us a sample for example, please describe it, its periodicity, its size, etc.

Comment: What is a "notch"? And what is "expected"?

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have %GDP and P(Default). One simple and efficient estimate to answer your question of how much P(Default) would increase / decrease if GDP increases by 1 unit (%) is to use a linear regression model. This is given by the coefficient/ slope of the regression line.

If you are familiar with excel and if the data is  small, then [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkNubKibM0A) will help you do it.